# How do you get the Google Analytics Client ID in a Hubspot form hidden field?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, hubspot

We are looking to establish the GA 360 and Salesforce integration, however we use Hubspot forms that pass the information to Salesforce.  What type of Java script or setup would need to take place in order to get the Google Analytics Client ID in to hidden fields in our Hubspot forms, similar to the 'Form' section in this help article for Salesforce? (total noob so I appreciate the help!)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7584446?hl=en

Comment: Where is your Google Analytics Client ID stored? Can you share the relevant code from the Hubspot form(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't yet have access for the code (temp work, still obtaining personal access).  Currently, we are pulling the Client ID from the analytics.js library that loads on each page and are now storing that in GA as a custom dimension as well via GTM.  Wondering how to pull it in a similar way to the Hubspot forms.